# Mongo connector and Neo4j doc manager shows no graph

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I have installed neo4j doc manager as per the document. When I try to sync my mongodb data using the below command it waits infinitely:

```
Python35-32>mongo-connector -m l
ocalhost:27017 -t http://localhost:7474/db/data -d neo4j_doc_manager
Logging to mongo-connector.log.
```

The content of mongo-connector.log is as follows:

```
2016-02-26 19:10:11,809 [ERROR] mongo_connector.doc_managers.neo4j_doc_manager:70 - Bulk
```

The content of oplog.timestamp is as follows:

```
["Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, replicaset='myDevReplSet'), 'local'), 'oplog.rs')", 6255589333701492738]
```

EDIT:
If I initialize the mongo-connector with -v option, the mongo-connector.log file looks like the below:

> 2016-02-29 15:17:18,964 [INFO] mongo_connector.connector:1040 -
>   Beginning Mongo Connector 2016-02-29 15:17:19,005 [INFO]
>   mongo_connector.oplog_manager:89 - OplogThread: Initializing oplog
>   thread 2016-02-29 15:17:23,060 [INFO] mongo_connector.connector:295 -
>   MongoConnector: Starting connection thread
>   MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict,
>   tz_aware=False, connect=True, replicaset='myDevReplSet') 2016-02-29
>   15:17:23,061 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:158 - OplogThread:
>   Run thread started 2016-02-29 15:17:23,061 [DEBUG]
>   mongo_connector.oplog_manager:160 - OplogThread: Getting cursor
>   2016-02-29 15:17:23,062 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:670 -
>   OplogThread: reading last checkpoint as Timestamp(1456492891, 2) 
>   2016-02-29 15:17:23,062 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:654 -
>   OplogThread: oplog checkpoint updated to Timestamp(1456492891, 2)
>   2016-02-29 15:17:23,068 [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:178 -
>   OplogThread: Got the cursor, count is 1 2016-02-29 15:17:23,069
>   [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:185 - OplogThread: about to
>   process new oplog entries 2016-02-29 15:17:23,069 [DEBUG]
>   mongo_connector.oplog_manager:188 - OplogThread: Cursor is still alive
>   and thread is still running. 2016-02-29 15:17:23,069 [DEBUG]
>   mongo_connector.oplog_manager:194 - OplogThread: Iterating through
>   cursor, document number in this cursor is 0 2016-02-29 15:17:24,094
>   [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:188 - OplogThread: Cursor is
>   still alive and thread is still running. 2016-02-29 15:17:25,095
>   [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:188 - OplogThread: Cursor is
>   still alive and thread is still running. 2016-02-29 15:17:26,105
>   [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:188 - OplogThread: Cursor is
>   still alive and thread is still running. 2016-02-29 15:17:27,107
>   [DEBUG] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:188 - OplogThread: Cursor is
>   still running.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing went wrong with my installation.

The data added to mongodb after the mongo-connector service started is automatically displayed in Neo4j. The data which are available in Mongodb before the service is started cannot be loaded into Neo4j.